# Jquery or vb.net code for checking future date entered in textbox

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I have below code in vb.net.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <b>Course Date:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="CourseTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseDT") %>' />        
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to check at client end whether the entered date in text box is future date. I mean this textbox should allow future date only.

Please provide the code the above problem using jquery or vb.net

Comment: @Manoj - You already have asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357289/vb-net-regular-expresion-for-future-date, if the answers there are not satisfactory please edit the question so that we can answer it there instead of re-asking the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish client side validation using a combination of two ASP.NET validation controls.  CompareValidator and RangeValidator.

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" Type="Date" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Operator="DataTypeCheck" />
<asp:RangeValidator id="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" 
MinimumValue="2009-01-01" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" />
```

Then on the page, on initial load, update the "minimumvalue" property based on the current date.